# Copy multiple rasterfiles into geopackage

Tags: qgis, convert, geopackage

I have a folder with ~100+ raster images which covers my study area (the data comes in .ecw or .tiff, i have both at hand). How do i get them into one geopackage without having to go the export -> geopackage -> select the geopackage -> select a layer name etc. way for every single file?

So far i tried to create a .vrt with all the rasters and export this into the gpkg, which suceeded, but when i want to open it, it is loading for ages. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you can just drag and drop files into a geopackage in the Browser panel.